# Cleanup unused old large files in version control

Tags: version-control, mercurial

For my current project I'm using Mercurial and hosting it on Bitbucket.

This was the first project I really properly used version control for, so I made a few mistakes starting out. One of these is that I stored all the (uncompressed) sound files that my project uses in the repository with the code.

As a result, right now even though I am no longer storing these files there, pulling for the first time from the server still takes quite a long time (I am guessing that the repository saves all of that so that I can recover back those files if I wanted to?) and the project occupies more space than it should.

It's not a huge issue, but I'm wondering what would be a good way to fix it now. Also, would this "destructive" editing of the repository affect "compatibility" with other forks (i.e. would create problems pushing changes between forks)?

Thanks! If any more details are needed, please just ask in the comments.

Similar/related to: [How to cleanup Mercurial repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803974/how-to-cleanup-mercurial-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`convert` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap) and command to rebuild the repo and remove specific files while doing so. However, as you guessed correctly, this kind of changes do create new changeset hashes and therefore break the "compatibility" with other forks.

Comment: Repository integrity is a double-edged sword in this way, and such mistakes we will have to live with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, judging by the way I understand hashes work with mercurial, if I do the same exact operation (say remove some file A from changeset X), in both repo 1 and its fork 2 (where the fork happens in a changeset that's a later descendant of X), shouldn't they get rehashed in the same way (and thus continue being compatible)? (I will actually test this on some copies of my repos and see if it's achievable)

Comment: No, because the reference to the parent changeset is also included, which makes the hash change if the parent isn't identical.

Comment: But I'm suggesting that I edit the parent in the same way. Let's put it this way (letters are changesets). Main repo: A->B->C->D->E; Fork: A->B->C->F->G ; Now I go and do the convert operations that will affect the repo starting with changeset B (say, I exclude a file that was added in B and that is unchanged in both main and fork), in the exact same way, in both repos. I should now get new hashes, but the same between the main repo and fork, no? I'll actually give this a try later on some dummy repos and see what happens :)

Comment: And yes, I know that the above is a very specific situation and I understand that outside of it it would most probably not work :) But this case actually applies to my problem very well since I have some files that have remained unchanged through both repos and I just want them permanently out of the system.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, would this "destructive" editing of the repository affect "compatibility" with other forks?

Yes, it will. Good thinking on your part! It will be effectively a new repository.